# Running Python Hive UDF in Spark: hive syntax

Tags: python, hive, user-defined-functions, using

I am trying to run a user defined function in hive using python as the udf language.

I am using the following syntax for the hive function call

ADD FILE /home/pentaho/mg/SevDev.py; # this is the location of my python function

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE mg_test_results
SELECT
TRANSFORM (x,y)
USING 'SevDev.py'
AS (a,b)
FROM mg_test_interim;

As you can see, I have added the python script to Hive, but I am unsure that I have the 'USING SevDev.py' part correct. Is this the correct syntax for USING?

Comment: have you tried `USING 'python SevDev.py'` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried USING 'python SevDev.py' and also USING 'python ./SevDev.py' and also USING '/usr/bin/ python ./SevDev.py'. Still getting the same error: